# Visual studio 2012 TFS replace local version with latest version from cloud

Tags: visual-studio

I am just starting out on Visual studio TFS, and we are tying to figure out is there a way other then going into the folder and deleting all the local files by had, to force the local files to be replaced with our files on the cloud? We want to have everything deleted and just have the latest version and none of the files we have created locally. we are doing this so that we can have fresh versions of our site at the beginning of new projects.